# How do I write a Express router to exclude a path

Tags: node.js, express

I have a site that I'm writing a top of page routine that runs on every page:

```
app.all("*",function(req,res,next){
  https.get("this.site.com/api", do_stuff);
  next();
}
```

And then I realize part of that function hits /api on my own site, which means when it does it will try to call itself, infinitely.

Only the pages under /api need exclusion, so writing a route that does as little as possible makes the most sense.

I also saw an example somewhere that looked like true regex can be used, but I couldn't make that work either.

I tried...

```
app.all("!(/api*)*", ...
```

and

```
app.all(/!(\/api.*).*/
```

...but those doesn't seem to let anything through. I can't find exclusions in the docs, is this something Express can handle? If so, how?

Comment: Just catch it normally and don't call `next()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put programming logic inside your middleware:

```
app.all("*",function(req,res,next){
  if (req.originalUrl.startsWith('/api')) {
      // skip any /api routes
      next();
  } else {
      https.get("this.site.com/api", do_stuff);
      next();
  }
}
```

---

A cleaner overall design would be to insert a `/api` router BEFORE this middleware and make sure that it handles its own 404 errors (so it never allows routing to continue to other route handlers).

```
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

// no /api routes will get here
app.all("*",function(req,res,next){
  https.get("this.site.com/api", do_stuff);
  next();
}
```